# NSURLConnection:didReceiveResponse: called in addition to didFailWithError:

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I've noticed that if there is a connection problem then didReceiveResponse: is getting called in addition to didFailWithError: (with HTTP 400).

This isn't what I was expecting and makes dealing with error situations tricky - especially because I have also noticed didReceiveResponse: is something getting called before didFailWithError: and sometimes after it.

I can't believe this is intended behavior, and am therefore wondering is there is somehow some problem with my code, but if there is I can't imagine how.

Can anybody confirm what the behavior of NSURLConnection should be in or if they've seen behavior like this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this is working as intended. The `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` and `connection:didFailWithError:` methods are mutually exclusive, but either one can be proceeded by a call (or many!) to `connection:didReceiveResponse:`.

After all, you *did* receive a valid HTTP response in this case. It just happens to be one that indicates that your request couldn't be processed because of some issue with that request. (As opposed to, say, a timeout, where the loading failed, but there was never a response.)

However, one of `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` or `connection:didFailWithError:` should always be the *last* message you get for a given connection. (If you're using a single delegate for many connections, make sure you're looking at the same connection object when you see these calls out of order.)

Comment: Sixteen is correct. Usually you just empty out your data buffer in didReceiveResponse.

Comment: If didReceiveResponse: is called before didFailWithError: in this situation above, is there a way of determining within didReceiveResponse what the HTTP status code is so that the processing in there can adapt as necessary?

Comment: Sure: the second argument is an `NSHTTPURLResponse` (assuming an HTTP request), which has the status code, the headers, and so on. The only tricky thing is that you _only_ get this passed to you there, and _not_ in either the finish or failure methods, so you might need to stash it (or the info it contains) in some kind of data structure if you'll need it there, too.